# What's the fastest way to earn Connected: Criminals?

Tags: fallen-london

In Echo Bazaar, I have maxed out my stats and become a Person of Some Importance. I want to raise my Connected: Criminals so I can use an Opportunity card.

I've bought the Old Bone Skeleton Key, but I can't use it, because my Connected: Criminals is less than 10. (And I don't want to spend real money on this.)

How can I raise my Connected: Criminals?

Answer (score 9):

Generally there are quests around the Flit or Wolfstack Docks that will do some good, and obviously playing opportunity cards that will commit dodgy deeds or frustrate the Constables are likely to help.

As long as you have a Connected: Criminals of at least three, then you can go to Mrs Plenty's Carnival.  Buy or steal some carnival tickets, then go to the sideshows.  From there you should be able to exchange tickets for Connected: Criminals by associating with the criminals. This should enable you to get your Connected up to 10 and use the key.

Also, here is a large list of things that will increase your Connected: Criminals. http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Criminals

Good luck.

Comment: Once you're at 16, and neither the carnival or the key will help, the best grind seems to be casing and then selling information, especially if you've a gang of hoodlums for the casing.